# Best approach to create a form master style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, architecture

I'm currently in a DotNetNuke with bootstrap 3.3 project and i was tasked to create a master style for an unknown number of html forms, that can be applyed in an unknown number of websites and it can't ruin the applyed style of some contact forms.

What i have in mind is,

To have the correct hierarchy i thought of adding a master class to the specific forms that would aquire that specific styling, but I'm reticent on doing this because it would imply adding manualy that class,

Am i thinking correctly or is there a better way?

Comment: If by "a donnetnuke" you mean "a CMS", aren't all its pages structured in most the same way? Then you can just add CSS based on the HTML structure rather than having to add classes by hand.

Comment: Sorry, typo  correct:DotNetNuke
No, the pages have very different structures and they may or may not be "under" the CMS